# New user validates without confirming email

Tags: plugin-development, users, plugins, registration

I've built a plugin that does some work before saving the user from the standard Registration Form. My only issue is it does not fire the activation email which I added in. But it lets the user login without verification, so I'd like to know what I'm missing as I thought if I `use craft()->users->saveUser()` it automatically deals with this for new users. My code is as follows I think I may be missing something from the model?

```
$newUser = new UserModel();
$newUser->username = $username;
$newUser->email = $email;
$newUser->newPassword = $password;

$success = craft()->users->saveUser($newUser);

if ($success)
    {
        // Code added to send email
        craft()->users->sendActivationEmail($newUser);

        $this->redirectToPostedUrl($newUser);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're bypassing Craft's own [UsersController->actionSaveUser()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/controllers/UsersController#actionSaveUser-detail), you'll need to replicate a bit more of its functionality in order for it to work like you're wanting.

First you'll want to make sure that "Require Email Verification" is checked under `Settings->Users->Settings` in the control panel.

Then your `UserModel` will also need to set a few more things:

```
$user->unverifiedEmail = $email;
$user->pending = true;
```

Completely untested, but that should do it.

I highly recommend looking over Craft's default actionSaveUser implementation as there are many permissions/security guards in place for public registration that you should probably consider as well.

Comment: Cheers @bradbell It works well. Will definitely look over the default actionSaveUser.